# Second website Tax Configuration not working (Including tax, Excluding tax)

Tags: configuration, magento2, tax

In my *Magento 2(2.4.5)* Store, There are Two Websites, "**Main website**" and "**B2B Website**", and I want to *Show Price **Including Tax** in "**Main Website**" and In "**B2B Website**", I want to Show Price with **Excluding Tax***. I have set Configuration Properly. but In "B2B Website", still shows price with Including Tax, Whereas If I change Config in "Main Website" it works in "Main Website", but In "B2B Website" it does not affect any of this Configuration.

[Tax Display Settings]
**Main Website:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQbPK.png 
**B2B Website:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kYIo.png 
**And Tax Rules and Zone Settings:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eGpO.png

Tax Calculation Based on set with Shipping Address, so here's Screenshot of my Test Shipping and Billing Address
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Aru.png